# Sublime text regular expressions tmLanguage

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, tmlanguage

I am trying to modify a the xml file for a `tmLanguage` and i want to add a keyword to match `word=`. I can use obviously use regex to find `word` but when i add the `=` sign it can't find `word=`. I tried to escape the character but no luck. Any other ideas?

```
    <dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>(?:\b(word=)\b)</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>keyword.other.ixml</string>
    </dict>
```

Comment: remove the second \b

Comment: That worked. Following another persons template,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have word boundaries at both ends of `word=` and that means `word=` should be preceded by a non-word character (as the first `\b` is before a word character `w`) and followed by a word character (as the second `\b` is after a non-word character). [It matches `,word=n`](https://regex101.com/r/sA8xI3/1), for example.

More details about a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
>
>   After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
>
>   Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

If you plan to match `word=` in all cases where it *starts* with `w`, just use the first `\b` and remove the last one.

So, replace `<string>(?:\b(word=)\b)</string>` with:

```
<string>\bword=</string>
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sA8xI3/2)

I also removed unnecessary groupings `(...)`.

As an alternative, if you just do not want non-word characters appear before and after the `word=, use lookarounds:

```
<string>(?<!\w)word=(?!\w)</string>
```